# Recursive algorithm complexity with for loop

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

I have a recursive algorithm like:

```
void bishopSolver(int level, int i, int board[][N]){
    int size = 63 - (6 -  level);
    for (; i < size; i+=2){
        addToMap(level, i);
        if(level == 3 && isFull(board)){
            printout();
            return;
        }
        if (level < 3){
            bishopSolver(level + 1, i + 2, board);
        }
        removeFromMap(level);
    }
}
```

As I see it, if it have recursion and one for loop, the complexity would be `n`, but I'm not sure about that. Could anyone tell me average-case and worst-case scenario complexities?

Comment: what is `n` , you are trying to calculate the complexity comparing to what ? `N`, `i` or `level` ??

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is `O(n^4)`, assuming you start from `level==0`.

You have `size` recursive calls when `level==0`.

Each of them is cuasing `size` recursive calls at `level==1`, totalling in `size^2` so far.

Each of them is causing `size` recursive calls at `level==2`, totalling in `size^3`.

At level 3, each of these calls are looping `size` more times, giving you `size^4`

Assuming `size` is `O(n)` (or specifically, assuming `size==n-(6-level)` , you get `O(n^4)` complexity, with further assumptions of course that `printout()`, `removeFromMap()`  and `addToMap()` are O(1) (otherwise need to factor them as well).

Comment: size has only 4 possible values, you can't calculate complexity of the algorithm depending on that

Comment: @Othman I assume size is hard coded here not by intent, and in fact `63` is the size of the input.

Comment: well he didn't mention that, you'are probably right, but complexity has no meaning in the code he gived